# what is the purpose of MediaCache folder on a Mac

Tags: macos, filesystem, web-browsing

What is the purpose of `/private/var/folders/zg/jjtx0_k94pdc5p5q6gcvf4900000gn/T/MediaCache` folder? It looks like some sort of database. I noticed it gets updated while browsing quite often.

Excerpt from one of files looks like elvish.

```
ÈÈ+˚Cªå¢jß…ΩˇáOÏ??’¸¯ëor≥Ã=-¥PÊ6°æ¥RÌKlà
¬ÿ/çßˇçf9¥Cë+™ÕôöOÌfÓ€ß3W e5uèOn‘~Ê∞µMp8‚oIîôTôˆJs;ÓëZ⁄Ó‰ì
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a disk cache for any media files (video, audio) you watch in browser. *CachedMedia-* seems to be a cached chunk of media data and *diskcacherepository.plist* is an index file of URL <-> media chunk relations.
[image: diskcacherepository.plist contents]